# Why are my backslashes disappearing in my Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, command-line, escaping

I tried a search and replace across all files in a directory as follows:

```
/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s/Else/Else  FILE_WRITE(\"C:\\TestDir\\mes.txt","Message received");/g"            *.scr
```

That is replace all occurence of `Else` with `"Else  FILE_WRITE(\"C:\TestDir\mes_.txt","Message received");"`

But the replacement is seen to be as follows:

```
Else  FILE_WRITE("C:TestDir^@mes.txt);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a shell question, not a Perl question.

You need to escape the slashes in the filename, otherwise the shell will interpret them as escape sequences.

What you have right now:

```
$ echo "s/Else/Else FILE_WRITE(\"C:\TestDir\mes.txt","Message received");/g"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

What you want:

```
$ echo "s/Else/Else FILE_WRITE(\"C:\\TestDir\\mes.txt\",\"Message received\");/g"
s/Else/Else FILE_WRITE("C:\TestDir\mes.txt","Message received");/g
```

In the future, try to use single quotes instead of double quotes.  Then you can write without escaping:

```
$ echo 's/Else/Else FILE_WRITE("C:\TestDir\mes.txt","Message received");/g'
s/Else/Else FILE_WRITE("C:\TestDir\mes.txt","Message received");/g
```

Perl's flexible q and qq operators are also helpful:

```
$ perl -e 'print q{A double quote looks like this -> "}'
A double quote looks like this -> "
```

Comment: Still after replacement the backslash is missing. The following are see in files after replacement.

Else FILE_WRITE("C:TestDirmes.txt","Message received");

Comment: You have to escape the slashes from Perl too.

Comment: Single quotes don't mean anything to the Windows cmd.exe shell so you can't use them to quote your arguments.

Comment: A handy thing is that, in many places, Windows will accept 'C:/TestDir/mes.txt' instead of 'C:\TestDir\mes.txt'. That might make it easier to handle the quoting.